# java finding longest growing sequence of an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Lets say I have an array. {3,2,5,7,10,1,5,7,11,15}.
I want to find longest increasing series of this array. 
For example {2,5,7,10} and {1,5,7,11,15} are the increasing series of this array but the second one is longer.

Comment: Show us what you're having *trouble* with. Right now this question is too broad.

Comment: Example not clear

Answer (score 0):

This was sort of fun to do so show i'll show it

```
    int[] allNumbers = {3,2,5,7,10,1,5,7,11,15,1,2,3};
    ArrayList<Integer> series = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> currentLongestSeries = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int index = 0; index < allNumbers.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println("Checking " + allNumbers[index] + "\nCurrent series is " + Arrays.toString(series.toArray()));
        //starting condition
        if(series.size() == 0)
        {
            series.add(allNumbers[index]);
        }
        //adding to our series
        else if(series.get(series.size() - 1) < allNumbers[index])
        {
            series.add(allNumbers[index]);
        }
        //check how big our list is
        else
        {
            if(series.size() > currentLongestSeries.size())
            {
                currentLongestSeries = series;
                series = new ArrayList<>();
                series.add(allNumbers[index]);
            }
            else
            {
                series = new ArrayList<>();
                series.add(allNumbers[index]);
            }
            System.out.println("Current biggest series is " + Arrays.toString(currentLongestSeries.toArray()));
        }
    }
    //now lets check one last time because we still have a series to check
    if(series.size() > currentLongestSeries.size())
    {
        currentLongestSeries = series;
        System.out.println("Current biggest series is " + Arrays.toString(currentLongestSeries.toArray()));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Last series is " + Arrays.toString(series.toArray()));
    }
    System.out.println("FINAL SERIES is " + Arrays.toString(currentLongestSeries.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this homework is to iterate over the array, creating a list of elements that ascend in value as you go.

Once you hit a value that is not larger, check this list with your previous list: if longer, replace the previous list.

There are many ways to accomplish this task. Here's my version:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TheLongestSequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = new int[]{3,2,5,7,10,1,5,7,11,15};

        // Prime the pump with the first element
        int previous = myArray[0];
        List<Integer> longestArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> currentArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        currentArray.add(previous);

        // Cycle through the array
        for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] > previous) {
                currentArray.add(myArray[i]);
            } else {
                previous = myArray[i];
                // Check if this array is larger than the previous one
                if (currentArray.size() > longestArray.size()) {
                    longestArray = currentArray;
                }

                currentArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                currentArray.add(myArray[i]);
            }
        }

        // Double check the last array isn't the longest one
        if (currentArray.size() > longestArray.size()) {
            longestArray = currentArray;
        }

        System.out.println(longestArray);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
[1, 5, 7, 11, 15]
```